# How to check current open connections on redis master

Tags: redis

I am trying to see if I can find out how many open client connections are there on the redis master server.
I tried `INFO Stats` command but that one only gives me total_connections_received which doesn't really give me what I need.

Apart from this, I ran `INFO Commandstats` and can't really understand the following output completely

```
cmdstat_setex:calls=8,usec=96,usec_per_call=21
```

In redis documentation, it doesn't really say what are the units of these numbers. Does it really mean that every setex call takes 21 seconds to complete?
I am wondering how to read this line. What is it really trying to convey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to check current open connections on redis master

You can use the [CLIENT LIST](https://redis.io/commands/client-list) command to get the current connection list.

> cmdstat_setex:calls=8,usec=96,usec_per_call=21

It means there're 8 `setex` calls, and these calls cost 96 microseconds of user time. So the average time of each call is `96 / 8 = 12` microseconds.

Comment: so it would mean a total of 8 setex calls ever since the redis master started?

Comment: YES and NO. These counters might be reset with the `CONFIG RESETSTAT` command.